bluetooth stopped working on CachyOS
I've always had problems with the Bluetooth in this distro , it ended up being half-assed by un mounting and re mounting btusb using modprobe. After that i could use it for a mouse. It wasn't perfect like on android but good enough.
Then one day i had the need to send files via bluetooth and installed blueman (was only using it for the mouse before ). I couldn't send the files (the computer refused to recieve them despite beng configured to accept them). Then, not sure if i did an update with pacman, the mouse started acting choppy (the curor moviing like an inch on the screen), instead of smooth. I checked the milisecond times (as they suggest for choppy mouse) in the device file and they seem fine . Then I loaded modprobe with enable_autosuspend=0 and it worked only once afterwards. to the next power on it was still choppy and suddenly the choppyness increased progressively until it took almost a minute to effect the action on the mouse like clicks and moving the cursor (yes, around one minute).  Which is of course unusable. Now it's extra hard to get the bluetooth to get to detect the moue or any other bluetooth device. Curiously, bluetoothctl didn't react in it's shell when first loaded and took around the same amount of time as the mouse to show all the keys that were pressed. (Now it works seemingly normmally but detecting the devices)
I have reinstalled bluez, bluez-utils, deleted the /etc/bluetooth/ directory and reinstalled bluez, installed and uninstalled mkinitcpio-bluetooth and remade the mkinitcpio, restarted the service, looked at journalctl and the output of the systemctl status, and the btmon (btmoon now wont work).
AutoEnable=true in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf has always been there it seeems.
The only seemingly bad thing i get from them is https://pastes.io/lrprm5mmah
I lost the command to see  bluez log, maybe there's something else there
That's how it's going.
Thank you in advance!

what arch-based distro are you on?

@cinemassacres CachyOS
